# fade in fade out and stop on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m working on small animation where the link will have fadein fadeout effect with some delay but when when user moveover his mouse on link it should stop and start animate once again once mouse out.

Currently When user moveover mouse on link 2 or more link start appering and its stop at last.

https://jsfiddle.net/e1fye4uy/3/

```
function InOut(elem) {
elem.delay()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(10000)
    .fadeOut(1000,

function () {
    if (elem.next().length > 0) {
        InOut(elem.next());
    } else {
        InOut(elem.siblings(':first'));
    }

}).mouseover(function () {
    //$(this).stop(true, false);
   // $(this).clearQueue();
    elem.stop($(".newsFlash").children('li'), true, false);
}).mouseout(function () {
    if (elem.next().length > 0) {
        elem.clearQueue();
        // elem.finish();
        InOut($(this));
    }
});};$(function () {
$('#content li').hide();
InOut($('#content li:first'));
```

});

Comment: Would it be ok to try a CSS3 approach using animation or must it be a javascript solution?

Comment: Sorry i cant use css3 approch. its should be javascript or jquery solution.

Comment: I think creating a function with setTimeout could help.. then you can "clear" the timeout on hover event

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution
https://jsfiddle.net/e1fye4uy/8/

```
var doAniamtion = false;
var lis = $("#content li");
var time;
function start(){
    time = setInterval(function(){ 
       next(); 
    }, 2000);
    console.log("start" + time);
}

function stop(){
    console.log("stop " + time)
    clearInterval(time);
}



function next(){
    var lisLength = $(lis).length;
    for(var i=0;i<lisLength;i++)
        if($(lis[i]).hasClass("current"))
        {
            fadOut(lis[i],function(){
                fadIn(((i+1) < lisLength) ? lis[i+1] : lis[0]);
            });
            return;
        }
}

function fadIn(obj, callback){
    $(obj).addClass("current");
    $(obj).animate({
        opacity:1
    },500,function(){

        callback && callback();
    });
}

function fadOut(obj, callback){
    $(obj).addClass("current");
    $(obj).animate({
        opacity:0
    },500,function(){
         $(obj).removeClass("current");
        callback && callback();
    });
}

start();

$("#content").mouseover(function(){
    stop();
});

$("#content").mouseout(function(){
    start();
});
```

So, I decide to use animation instead of use fadeIn and fadeOut, setInterval (+info http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and class "current" in the li HTML element to know witch li is current visible.

***PS:***

For change the time that li remains visible change the setInterval Time.
For make the animations more fast or slow change the time in animation inside of fadIn and fadout functions

Any doubt about the code, ask!